# Hibernate : All tables in SQL Server database are not auto-created

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, glassfish-4, jpa-2.1

create tables from Java in database on Microsoft SQL Server 2012. All tables are created, except one table. I'm using JPA and there is my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="teknikPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/teknikNDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.royken.entities.Bloc</class>
    <class>com.royken.entities.Elements</class>
    <class>com.royken.entities.Organes</class>
    <class>com.royken.entities.SousOrganes</class>
    <class>com.royken.entities.Utilisateurs</class>
    <class>com.royken.entities.Zone</class>
    <class>com.royken.entities.Reponse</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
      <!--            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent" value="false"/>-->
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/> -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is how I define my classes :

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "elements")
@Table(name = "ELEMENTS")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Elements implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "elements")
    private List<Reponse> reponses;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "NOM")
    private String nom;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default true", name = "HASBORNS")
    private boolean hasBorns;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default true", name = "CRITERIAALPHA")
    private boolean criteriaAlpha;

}
```

I have defined 7 tables like that, but only 6 tables are created, Elements tables is not created. When I change the datasource by using a mysql database (without changing any part of code), all my tables are well created.
What can be the issue ?
The image bellow shows the result in SQL server, Elements table is not present.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Entity table was not created because SQL Server does not accept **true** as default value for **hasborns** and **criteriaalpha**. Also, it does not now the size to allocate to **tinyint** type. So it throws an error during table creation. To solve this issue, I replaced:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default true", name = "HASBORNS")
private boolean hasBorns;

@Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default true", name = "CRITERIAALPHA")
private boolean criteriaAlpha;
```

with:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "BIT default 1", name = "HASBORNS", length = 1)
private boolean hasBorns ;

@Column(columnDefinition = "BIT default 1", name = "CRITERIAALPHA", length = 1)
private boolean criteriaAlpha ;
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

In your `persistence.xml` Use :

```
<property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
```

In your code, you may use:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import entity.userEntity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
```

Look for EntityManager

```
 @PersistenceContext
            private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and then use it like :

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Elements e WHERE e.id= :idValue");
            query.setParameter("idValue", 1);
            Elements elements = null;
            try {
                elements = (Elements) query.getSingleResult();
} catch (NoResultException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

You may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489359/entity-table-is-not-creating-using-jpa-2-1/#25489941)

If that too doesn't help look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618802/when-i-run-program-jpa-does-not-create-table-in-mysql/#46620422)

Comment: Hello @Surajit, I tried but it is not working. 06 tables are automatically created and one is not. While on MySQL all the tables are automatically created with the same code.